# Unstuffed to Stuffed Two Stroke Engine

Tags: motors, airflow, engines, combustion, fuel

I'm working on a Puch e50 Engine.

The original engine used an unstuffed crank that had bushings instead of bearings.  I've rebuilt the engine using new seals, bearings, and an aftermarket stuffed crankshaft.  I've re-used the original top end, but honed the cylinder and installed new rings.

The carb, head and cylinder are all the same.  I've leakdown tested the engine and confirmed no leaks.  Everything is stock except for an aftermarket crankshaft.

I'm having an issue getting the engine to idle.  Even with the idle adjustment screw all the way in on the original carb, it will not idle. Only way to get it to idle is by increasing the throttle tension to its max setting and keeping the slide up more.  Theoretically, the engine should idle even with no throttle cable attached...

Would moving from an unstuffed to a stuffed crank require a different air/fuel mix at idle and cause my idling issues?

Comment: a stuffed crank is a barely noticeable change to the engine.  Something else is off.

Comment: `it will not idle` . . what does it do?